# How to run multiprocessing on an array of 200,000 values?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency

Lets suppose I have and array and with length of 200,000. I want to run a function on each one value of that array, I have to do this with ThreadPoolExecutor. How could I do this?

```
allIds = [...] #Len = 200000

def someFunc(id):
[...]

for id in allIds:
    cur = int(id)
    someFunc(id = cur)
```

How could I do the same thing, but faster?

Comment: You know there is difference between `multithreading` (i.e. using `ThreadPoolExecutor` you mention in the body - _... I have to do this with ThreadPoolExecutor..._) and `multiprocessing` you mention in the title (in which case you can use [`concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor)?

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
import concurrent.futures as cf
allIds = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] #Len = 200000

def someFunc(idd):
    time.sleep(3)
    return idd*2

with cf.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        future_to_mapping = [executor.submit(someFunc, i) for i in allIds]

for future in cf.as_completed(future_to_mapping):
    print(future.result())
```

If max_workers is None or not given, it will default to the number of processors on the machine, multiplied by 5